# Can't remap fields - map fields window is missing new table

Tags: crystal-reports, field

I have a Crystal Report with a database command:

[image: CR Database Expert]

The command has a join clause that can be removed and read from a table in the database, because it represents static data. I add this table (called _System) to the database expert:

[image: New table added]

Now I edit the command to remove the join and columns that reference this table. Since the report fields that depended on these columns are no longer mapped, this causes the Map Fields window to appear:

[image: CR map fields]

...which does not have the new table in it. If I cancel out of this I am back to where I originally was. If I hit OK without mapping, all of the unmapped fields on the report are deleted (suffice it to say... I was not expecting this >:( )

I have tried adding links between the command and the new table, and refreshing report parameters, but these have had no effect.

One workaround is to manually replace every field in the report, but this is very labour intensive.

---

Here is the outline of the command before:

```
SELECT ACT.Account_Code, ACT.Company, ACT.FName, --etc
       STM.CompanyName AS 'DLRName', STM.Address_1 AS 'DLRAddress', STM.City AS 'DlrCity' --etc
FROM Accounts AS ACT
    JOIN _System AS STM ON 1 = 1 
GROUP BY ACT.Account_Code, ACT.Company, ACT.FName, --etc
         STM.CompanyName, STM.Address_1, STM.City --etc
```

And after:

```
SELECT ACT.Account_Code, ACT.Company, ACT.FName, --etc
FROM Accounts AS ACT
GROUP BY ACT.Account_Code, ACT.Company, ACT.FName --etc
```

I have removed the `JOIN` on the _System table, and all referenced columns.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to not be recognizing your _system table as a new source.

I would :

1)   leave your command object SQL unchanged & get the issue worked out with the _System table, then

2)   ensure that you are able to establish a join between the command object fields and the _System table fields, and lastly

3)   then remap the fields.

Step two I suspect is the source of the problem, as your join condition is "ON 1 = 1" which I assume to mean that you may not have a common key field in both tables.

Note that your original command SQL selects STM.Companyname AS 'DLRName'.

Hence, crystal now know of a field called DLRName, but does not know of a field called CompanyName, hence it cannot make the association between DLRName in the old source, and CompanyName in the new source...

Likewise with the rest of the fields that are being moved from the command object to an attached table.   if no name match exists...Crystal cant make the connection.   However...it would list all unmatched fields that are on the report, and all unused fields in the recognized data sources, and allow you to specify the matches yourself.

But it does not...which tells me that something has gone wrong with the attempt to attach/open the _System table.   Hence..you need to get that worked out first, then make the field adjustments.

If this doesnt get you thru...then show some sample data so I can see how the two tables are relating ( ensure some examples exists where there is a row match from both tables ).

Comment: The two tables are not related at all, which is why I am taking _System out of the join. Unfortunately, there are no common key fields. I tried adding links between the aliased _System columns in the command, and the actual columns in the table, but this did not work for the map fields window.

It does seem to recognize _System as a new source, because closing the database expert gives the "More than one datasource or stored procedure has been used in this report" warning.

Comment: Ok...I'm missing the big picture here.   What is the objective of having the _System table there ?  What is it doing for you ?   When you run the original version of the report, are those fields populated ?

Comment: The _System table holds static information ([see example 1 here](http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/716)) used for populating the header of the report. I am trying to separate it out from the command without having to manually re-add all the report objects.

Comment: Ahhh...I think I see where you are going.   You want the data from the _System table to be shown in the Header..and the data from the command object to be shown in the details section, yes ?   If so..the clean solution is to create a subreport, embed that into the header.  The subreport will read from the _System table...and the main report will populate the details section from the command object.   I can show talk you thru a shortcut..just let me know if this is where you are heading.

Comment: That is best left to another question, as this one should stay on topic of the table missing from map fields window.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago.

Unfortunately I can't find anything online that helps, or maybe wasn't looking hard enough. I just noticed that in my case, that particular field that isn't showing in the map field dialogue box has `nvarchar(max)` as its datatype (in view).

I tried to force the datatype with `CAST(missingfieldname as nvarchar(20)) as missingfieldname` *(I did this in the view)*, and voila, it magically appears in the map field dialogue box.

It seems that field mapping dialogue box aren't showing fields with blob texts.

I know this question was asked 4 years ago. But hopefully, this comment could help future solution seekers regarding this absurd and weird problem. I just got lucky seeing what's unique about that particular missing field.